# sending ajax request but not getting right result.Js

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am trying to display the data fetched from database in the loop and between loop i call the function and send ajax request its not working.Actually its displays the only if i used alert command. If i used alert then the browser display the div and then alert if i clicked ok then  it displays the second div then again show alert.
Here is the js code

```
function like(divid,id,session) {
    var orgnldiv=document.getElementById(divid);
    var ndiv=document.createElement('DIV');
    var idd=id+5000;
    ndiv.id =idd;
    ndiv.className="likeclass";
    orgnldiv.appendChild(ndiv); 
    var dynamicdiv=document.getElementById(idd);
    var span=document.createElement('span');
    var spanid=idd+5000;
    span.id=spanid;
    span.className="spanclass";
    dynamicdiv.appendChild(span);

    var xmllhttp15;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp15=new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else {
        xmlhttp15=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp15.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xmlhttp15.readyState==4 && xmlhttp15.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(spanid).innerHTML=xmlhttp15.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp15.open("GET","spancount.php?postid="+id+"&userid="+session);
    xmlhttp15.send();
    // alert(spanid);
}
```

please suggest me what can be the reason of this problem my code is working well only if i use alert

Comment: A better option would be to go for jquery ajax. Your code looks fine. Maybe the problem is that you're making too many requests. Another thing you could try in this code is making the request synchronous instead i.e

Comment: xmlhttp15.open("GET","URL","TRUE");

Comment: @AmanGupta can to many request make problems ?

Comment: Yes in a way it can. The thing is that the concept of Ajax was made to make updates on a page  where refreshing the entire page would actually turn out to be a waste! Posting an explanation to this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code works when you use alert is because whenever the alert function is called. The program flow is paused. In other words, your loop wont continue to make another Ajax call until you dismiss the alert.As a result, the request gets handled properly and the response data appears in the span div. that is why I had mentioned to make your calls synchronous instead.

So to answer the question you asked in the comment, Yes at times too many Ajax calls can be a problem. Let's say that the loops runs more than 15-20 times, that means 15-20 simultaneous requests. Now, think about the number of times the same request is being handled by the php script? Definitely a problem here!

Even with Jquery Ajax, the chances of the loop completing successfully is also 50-50 actually because it all boils down to the amount of requests being made , the bandwidth being used and how the request is being processed at the server.

One possible way to fix this problem is : Rather than constantly requesting small peices of data again and again from the server in the loop, Make one Ajax call and get the entire data as json. Then, parse the json and append data to the spans by using the  particular span id to extract the relevant data from the json object.

You might have to do a little bit of tweaking in both the above javascript and spancount.php . But it will definitely Save you A LOT of bandwidth. You gotta consider the fact that more than one person could be using your site!!

Hope that cleared up things, all the best with your project :D